# Can't load http content on an https page?

Tags: html, http, https

I'm trying to embed and iFrame of an http website on an http page, but I heep getting the error:

```
The page at 'https:-url-' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://-url-': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site/25189561#25189561

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can make the iFrame source HTTPS, no you can't.