# How to allow http site in iframe inside https site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, iframe, ssl

Our website has contain SSL certificate. We used iframe in our website. But " iframe src= http:// " is not working. only display website which src is start with "https://". We got below error in consel when we used site which src is "http://".

[blocked] The page at '- website url here-' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from ' - iframe src here': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

So how we can display website which start with "http://" in iframe inside https website?
Please Help Me....

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have control over it, then buy an SSL certificate for the site you are running in an iframe.

2) Don't serve the page where you have an iframe over HTTPS (only if it's safe to do so!).

Comment: Our website is URL https://www.artistsintheplus.com/artist/myrna-braza/
it is artists website and so many artists are registered in this site.artist is added their external website. it is display is artist detail page  webiste tab. So We are not able to buy SSL for all external website.

Comment: It looks like there's an alternative here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site but it's really not ideal. The two options I have posted are still valid.