# Force all third party requests from Youku to be over https and not http

Tags: vue.js, https, insecure-connection, youku

I have a website that embeds the Youku video player. This player is loading some insecure resources (over http instead of https). The player itself is loaded over https as outlined in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764990/how-to-embed-a-youku-video-on-an-https-site), but it loads some insecure resources. The insecure resource in question can be accessed via https: https://g2.ykimg.com/052100015C8F58A9AD97EB1AC20B9132

Is there a way to force all request being made from my Vue app to be loaded via https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to include a meta tag in the header.

```
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```