# Display Non-SSL content with absolute URL on an SSL site using iframe

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ssl, iframe

How can one without issues, errors, or browsers misbehaving display Non-SSL content with absolute URL on an SSL site using iframe? Please anyone out there with an answer or a suggestion please assist. Thanks! (Also the content trying to load is .swf)

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: ssl proxy for the non ssl content

Comment: How about unsecuring a specific part of the site using .htaccess? but still maintain a user being logged in and able to navigate around between all other pages and the one non secure to display this content?

Comment: Don't display stuff in iframes on SSL sites. That's awful. I'm sure there are technical workarounds, but its still awful.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Peters beautifully answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189561/2930268).

Essentially, you create an SSL proxy for the non-SSL page.

For example, you could put a page https://example.org/mypage, which redirects to http://example.net/nohttpspage

Comment: you should have voted to close as duplicate not just aswered with a link to another question

Comment: Yes, I also voted for duplicate. Would you recommend not answering in this case?