# How to import javascript code from external website with different protocol

Tags: javascript, ssl

I use an advertisement system (popup) on my website, I have installed ssl certificate on it and all visitors will redirect to https mode, but javascript code doesn't load in https.. This is js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var popupsky_user_id = xxxx;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx/website/js"></script>
```

How can i use this js code on my website? Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
http://xxxxxxx/website/js
```

will be blocked on a https website so you need to reference https instead i.e.

```
https://xxxxxxx/website/js
```

Comment: It is not possible, Because xxxxxxx website doesn't use https protocol.. Is there any other idea?

Comment: this link is about a iframe but i think it will help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site use the ticked answer looks good to me.