# Chrome browser: Cannot launch python code visualizer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visualizer

[Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit), a code Visualizer is integrated within [CloudCoder](https://github.com/cloudcoderdotorg/CloudCoder) (an open source web-based programming exercise system). When I click on the **`Visualize`** button (to the left of the green bar in the screenshot below), only a blank window pops up. The visualizer doesn't show up with the code under question.

[image: CloudCoder]

This problem seems specific to all browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Opera) running on Windows 7 on a PC (I don't know if it works okay on Windows 8).

[image: PythonTutor]

To re-create the problem, click on this demo problem available at this [URL](https://cloudcoder.org/demo/#exercise?c=3,p=33) (userid: `guest`  password: `password`). Any ideas on how to get the Visualizer to work within the browser?

Comment: The link provided requires a login. Running python tutor from the first link works ok in chrome on Windows 8. Can you confirm if this works on windows 7 ok (As in is it just a problem when you use cloud coder).

Comment: Yes, the visualizer window does not launch from within CloudCoder. Here's the login details: userid: `guest`   password: `password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to check the dev console when anything goes wrong:

[image: insecure content error]

The message above is self-explanatory, but unfortunately pythontutor.com does not seem to support HTTPS (it responds, but with a "Forbidden" error page).
You should contact them and kindly ask them to upgrade, if you care about security.
In the mean time, see this question & answer for how to work around security:
[How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site)

(The problem isn't specific to Windows btw, I'm running OS X 10.10.5 with Chrome 48 dev.)

---

An entirely different approach in this particular case would be to simply [get the PythonTutor source code](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/tree/master/v3) and host it yourself.

Comment: The workarounds help fix the issue on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: @lifebalance You could [host it yourself](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/tree/master/v3)... is that an option?