# Is there anyway to call http site in https via iframe in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to call HTTP site in https via iframe in WordPress? IF you guys have any solution then please prove it.
Thank You

Comment: Whether it's WP or not, this should be a viable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25189561/1552948

Comment: Thank You, But this is not working

Comment: What have you tried? You need to give some more information than this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask