# Invoke html page in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I need to import into an iframe, a page from a website, but if I try it locally it works even if it shows me googlr ads, but if I go to see it on the internet network on the server, it does not work at all.

```
<iframe 
    name="principale" 
    src="http://www.adessoin.tv/index.php" 
    marginheight="50" 
    height="800" 
    width="100%" 
    allowfullscreen = "true" 
></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you accessing your page online via HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, to my page I log in via https

Comment: So can not you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing your page via HTTPS (mentioned in comments), your browser blocks the insecure connection to `www.adessoin.tv`.

You can't change the url of the iframe to HTTPS because they don't have a valid certificate. Talk to them, maybe the can be persuaded that a valid certificate is a good thing.

More information can be found in this question: [How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site#25189561)

Comment: Sorry but they are just the first weapons and I do not understand how I can do even looking at the post you've reported to me.

Comment: Then you're out of luck, I guess. You should at least talk to them an suggest they allow secure connections with a valid certificate (they're free now with Let's Encrypt!).