# iFrame using http source display on https website - is it possible?

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to inject the following iframe onto my https website:
[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chu5R.png)

Is it possible to use a http iframe on an https website?

This is the error I receive when I inject it currently:

The webpage at https://trk.slvrbck.net/aff_ad?campaign_id=191&aff_id=25171&format=iframe might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may include your http iframe in an https website. The https site will encrypt the http iframe once its data is being sent from client to server.

getting it to work is another deal on its own :
refer to this to get it to work
[How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site)

Comment: That will work. Using any of the methods on that page, could you show me what my code would look it?

<iframe src="http://trk.slvrbck.net/aff_ad?campaign_id=191&aff_id=25171&format=iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="300" height="250"></iframe><img src="http://strk.enlnks.com/aff_i?offer_id=3241&aff_id=25171&file_id=22839" width="1" height="1" />