# iframe being blocked because of mixed content even though both are https (chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, https

My site is loaded over https: https://example.com.

I am trying to load an iframe from another of my sites via this:

```
<iframe src="https://example.org/path" width="800" height="800">
```

It works fine in Safari but in Chrome I am getting:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.org/path'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Why is it reporting a problem with http://example.org/path, when I am clearly referencing http**s**://example.org/path in the iframe element?

If I load up https://example.org/path in Chrome, and examine the network tab, it seems that all the requests made while loading that page are https, so it isn't trying to load a http resource.

Is this a bug in Chrome (59)?

Comment: Does it show a little green lock saying that you're using SSL when you open the link you set in the iframe?

Comment: Yes. The actual link in the iframe is https : // www.barn2door.com/a/Qqnv5

Comment: So example.org (the url I am trying to load in iframe) is hosted on heroku, and is a cname for example.herokuapp.com. But it turns out if just use the heroku with subdomain for may app, the iframe loads fine. So atleast I have a work around for now. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: That sounds likely. It depends on whether the SSL certificate is registered for the herokuapp.com URL or the shortened URL (without herokuapp).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? In my case, ha-mim.org/kayitlar, iframe object is blocked across all browsers even though SRC points to HTTPS page on the same domain.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site) has the solution of the problem.