# Allowing http content inside https site

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, laravel-5

I have project hosted using https and i wanted to show http content inside an iframe. But my problem is when i load the site inside the http nothing shown on the page accept a warning "The page is trying to load script from unauthenticated sources".

```
<iframe id="demoSite" src="{{$product->demo_url}}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>
```

Many people will find this as an accepted answer. But in 2018 it doesn't give you the right answer. If you have doubt see the comments below of the post.
[How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site/25189561#25189561)

So anybody have the solution please help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Answer (score 2):

As Joe stated, you can't.

And there are [really good reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) for that. I still believe you can do it if you proxy the request trough your own secure server.

I advise against it, but in theory, you can create a service to serve the insecure content trough a 'safe' connection:

https://example.com/proxy-the-iframe?unsafe-url=http://yourunsafecontenthere.com

That's just bringing unsafe content into your website though.

The best option is: Don't use http inside https, or use http and accept the unsafe origin of the iframe.

Comment: will a proxy server help?