# Disable HTTPS on a single page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl

I've tried editing the htaccess file multiple times and have added the following lines to it at the end of the document to disable HTTPS on a single webpage. Unfortunately, these do not work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, NC]
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/suburl)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.my_site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

---

I used really simple SSL to convert my entire site to SSL then disabled it, but I still want to disable SSL on a single page because of an iframe issue where the website is not loading through HTTPS. If there are any workarounds, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can find instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25299417/7224402

Comment: @Dmitry Unfortunately that solution no longer works

Comment: Do you want to do this because you have an Iframe that is loaded over HTTP? So you prefer disable your website security than trying to fix this unsecure iframe?