# Access http website url from an https website

Tags: javascript, html, .net, iframe, https

I have an old php website that uses http and we want some of its pages on our new website.
So, I have a https website from which I am trying to call the http page within an iframe. Its a dynamic page and data is displayed based on the input.

BUT, I cannot load it. Is there a possible solution using which I can achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: Please show us the expected behaviour. We need more information and context. What is this 'php website'? Why try to use an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers block all http resources on https website for security purposes.

You can do the following:

- Migrate your old website to https (**recommended**)
- Use http on your new site (**not recommended**)
- Setup a https proxy server that forwards requests to your old http website. see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site) (**not recommended**)

Have in mind that if you use an https proxy, this doesn't mean that your website is secure, because you are requesting information from an insecure website and your proxy should trust the server where it is forwarding requests.